# Stack value of my row instead of having multiple

Tags: php, mysql

So I've got a table that looks like this:

```
username - item - amount
user1 - sword - 1
user1 - sword - 1
user1 - sword - 1
user2 - sword - 1
user2 - sword - 1
```

How do I make it so that when I add an item to one of the users, they stack like this instead:

```
username - item - amount
user1 - sword - 3
user2 - sword - 2
```

the code for adding item:

```
$sql = "insert into items (username, item, amount) values ('".$_SESSION['user_name']."', 'sword', '1')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create unique index for username and item column and use [`on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) so if same pairs for username and item occurs sum existing amount value with new one

```
create unique index items_username_item on items(username, item);

insert into items (username, item, amount) 
values ('".$_SESSION['user_name']."', 'sword', '1')
on duplicate key update amount = amount + values(amount);
```